# MS SQL Case nesting error but not nested

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a problem on MS SQL :
I'm using a CASE with many statements in my view, like this :

```
select
e.[Nom d'annuaire],
e.[Prénom annuaire],
f.[Nom d'annuaire en UTF-8] AS login,
e.Usagers as [Numéro interne],
d.[Numéro externe],
s.[Préfixe No abr direct],
v.fonction,

  CASE
           WHEN v.lib_delegation = 'Service informatique' THEN 'Euralille'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_national' THEN 'Maillot'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_tpe' THEN 'Maillot'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_paris-idf' THEN 'Maillot'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_grands-comptes' THEN 'Maillot'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'cotestrm' THEN 'Marcq en baroeul'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_sud-ouest' THEN 'Bruges'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_normandie' THEN 'Caen'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_bourgogne' THEN 'Dijon'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_ouest' THEN 'Ouest'
           WHEN v.lib_delegation = 'Centre Limousin' THEN 'Tours'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_est' THEN 'Nancy'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_mediterranee' THEN 'Aix'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_rhone-alpes' THEN 'Lyon'
           ELSE v.delegation
        END AS Délégation,
        v.lib_delegation

from ale e 

INNER JOIN ale f
on e.Usagers = f.Usagers AND f.[No alias] = 1 and e.[No Alias] = 0

INNER JOIN Delegation d
on f.Usagers = d.[No annuaire]

INNER JOIN V_users v
on v.LOGIN = f.[Nom d'annuaire en UTF-8]

LEFT OUTER JOIN svi s
on e.Usagers = s.[No d'appel] 

order by e.Usagers
```

As you can see, my CASE statements aren't nasted, because I'm using `WHEN... THEN ...` syntax and then I simply put `ELSE ... END` statement.

However, when I try to filter my output using for example filter :

```
WHERE [Délégation] = 'Euralille'
```

I just get 2 errors :
Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Msg 125, Level 15, State 4, Line 1

Explanation of the Error Numbers:

- Msg 8180 = Statement(s) could not be prepared.
- Msg 125 = Case expressions may only be nested to level %d.

(Sorry for the poor french traduction)
I've been looking for the answer on MS SQL Website, and on StackOverflow but the problem is always that the CASE statements are nasted. But to me, I'm not in this situation...

Thanks in advance, I'm quite a beginner in this world.

Comment: `Msg 125` appears to mean that you have too many (>10) `WHEN...THEN` clauses in the `CASE` statement. If I were you I'd move that data to a separate table and then perform a `JOIN`

Comment: also, it helps a lot to include actual error messages in your question (not only error number, severity, etc.)

Comment: A friend of mine told me that he is using a great number of CASE statements (also greater than in this example) and he doesn't get the same error. He doesn't understand neither...

Comment: I could include it, but actually this is french, and I'm bad translator...

Comment: I've included the error descriptions from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but instead of using `CASE`, have you considered putting the values into a mapping table and just `JOIN` on it? It's a lot easier to maintain because if you add new mappings then you just have to add them to the table; with your current solution you have to update your code.

Comment: This is a good idea, but actually my case is testing 2 differents things : v.lib_delegation and v.delegation. I don't know if it is compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you filter like this? Note that I put all of your query into a subquery and then applied the where clause afterwards:

```
select * from 
(select
e.[Nom d'annuaire],
e.[Prénom annuaire],
f.[Nom d'annuaire en UTF-8] AS login,
e.Usagers as [Numéro interne],
d.[Numéro externe],
s.[Préfixe No abr direct],
v.fonction,

  CASE
           WHEN v.lib_delegation = 'Service informatique' THEN 'Euralille'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_national' THEN 'Maillot'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_tpe' THEN 'Maillot'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_paris-idf' THEN 'Maillot'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_grands-comptes' THEN 'Maillot'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'cotestrm' THEN 'Marcq en baroeul'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_sud-ouest' THEN 'Bruges'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_normandie' THEN 'Caen'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_bourgogne' THEN 'Dijon'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_ouest' THEN 'Ouest'
           WHEN v.lib_delegation = 'Centre Limousin' THEN 'Tours'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_est' THEN 'Nancy'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_mediterranee' THEN 'Aix'
           WHEN v.delegation = 'test_rhone-alpes' THEN 'Lyon'
           ELSE v.delegation
        END AS Délégation,
        v.lib_delegation

from ale e 

INNER JOIN ale f
on e.Usagers = f.Usagers AND f.[No alias] = 1 and e.[No Alias] = 0

INNER JOIN Delegation d
on f.Usagers = d.[No annuaire]

INNER JOIN V_users v
on v.LOGIN = f.[Nom d'annuaire en UTF-8]

LEFT OUTER JOIN svi s
on e.Usagers = s.[No d'appel] 

order by e.Usagers) as subTotalQuery
WHERE [Délégation] = 'Euralille'
```

Comment: I tried this out, but I had to erase the `order by e.Usagers` because it isn't allowed in subrequests, and I get the same error.

Comment: Looks like you've got this problem: http://phe1129.wordpress.com/2006/02/21/case-level-in-linked-server-limitation/.  You cannot use more than 10 case statements in a linked server.

Comment: Thanks jle, I used a procedure to put all the cases, and then simply using EXEC 'Procedure-Name' 'MyArgument' works fine. Thanks again